# django DJA with swagger setting content-type

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-swagger

I want to use the JSON API format for our API and 
[django-rest-framework-json-api](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api) seems to work perfectly for that.

However, I also use swagger. Now DJA follows [content-negotiation-clients](http://jsonapi.org/format/#content-negotiation-clients)

Loading the swagger docs goes fine however when I want to try something it does not follows the JSON API content negotiation.
When I change the curl command and run it in the shell it goes fine.

How can I change Django swagger to add the Content-Type: 'application/vdn.api+json' ?

( it is basically this first problem [django-rest-framework-json-api/issues](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues/57) , however, she does not state how she solved that issue only the second issue)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the answer has been laid out here... https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues/314